# Setting private key permissions with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, permissions, pfx

I have a PowerShell script that installs pfx certificate into the *LocalMachine* certificate store. The function looks like this:

```
function Add-Certificate {
param
(
    [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]$pfxPath,

    [Parameter(Position=2, Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]$pfxPassword
)

    Write-Host "Installing certificate" -ForegroundColor Yellow

    try 
    {
        $pfxcert = new-object system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2
        $pfxcert.Import($pfxPath, $pfxPassword, [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]"PersistKeySet")

        $store = new-object system.security.cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store -argumentlist "MY", LocalMachine
        $store.Open([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]"ReadWrite");
        $store.Add($pfxcert);
        $store.Close();

        return $pfxcert
    }
    catch 
    {
        throw
    }
}
```

When I open the Certificate Manager to verify the installation I can see that it has installed correctly.

The next step in my process is to assign permissions to the certificate to a service account.

```
function Set-CertificatePermission
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$pfxThumbPrint,

        [Parameter(Position=2, Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$serviceAccount
    )

    $cert = Get-ChildItem -Path cert:\LocalMachine\My | Where-Object -FilterScript { $PSItem.ThumbPrint -eq $pfxThumbPrint; };

    # Specify the user, the permissions and the permission type
    $permission = "$($serviceAccount)","Read,FullControl","Allow"
    $accessRule = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule -ArgumentList $permission;

    # Location of the machine related keys
    $keyPath = $env:ProgramData + "\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\";
    $keyName = $cert.PrivateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.UniqueKeyContainerName;
    $keyFullPath = $keyPath + $keyName;

    try
    {
        # Get the current acl of the private key
        # This is the line that fails!
        $acl = Get-Acl -Path $keyFullPath;

        # Add the new ace to the acl of the private key
        $acl.AddAccessRule($accessRule);

        # Write back the new acl
        Set-Acl -Path $keyFullPath -AclObject $acl;
    }
    catch
    {
        throw $_;
    }
}
```

This function fails. Specifically, this function fails when trying to evaluate the Get-Acl command, with the following error: **Get-Acl : Cannot find path 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\59f1e969a4f7e5de90224f68bc9be536_1d508f5e-0cbc-4eca-a402-3e55947faa3b'**

As it turns out the key file has been installed into my roaming profile **C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-21-1259098847-1967870486-1845911597-155499**

I'm sure there is something wrong with the Add-Certificate function, but I cannot figure out what it is. How do I force it to install the key file in the C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys directory?

Comment: FYI, I know this doesn't address the main topic, but `try .. catch` statements will only catch terminating errors in PowerShell. Most cmdlets generate non-terminating errors, so to change them into terminating errors, use the `-ErrorAction` parameter on `Get-Acl` and set the value to `Stop`.

Comment: Thanks @TrevorSullivan, I'll make that change immediately.

Comment: You're quite welcome. Is there a reason you aren't using the `Import-PfxCertificate` cmdlet, by the way?

Comment: @TrevorSullivan As far as I am aware this is only available in Windows 2012.

Comment: What version of Windows and PowerShell are you running?

Comment: @TrevorSullivan I'm using PowerShell 4 on Windows 2008R2. The PKI module isn't available as a module on 2008.

Comment: One addition only: GetAccessControl in try-catch is not a cmdlet, needs to be in parentheses.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is the when the `X509Certificate2` was getting imported via the `Import()` method, the `X509KeyStorageFlags` were not configured to write the private key to the computer's private key store. I've updated the function to include the appropriate `X509KeyStorageFlags`.

```
function Add-Certificate {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$Path,

        [Parameter(Position=2, Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$Password
    )

    Write-Verbose -Message ('Installing certificate from path: {0}' -f $Path);

    try 
    {
        # Create the certificate
        $pfxcert = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 -ErrorAction Stop;
        $KeyStorageFlags = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::Exportable -bxor [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::MachineKeySet -bxor [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::PersistKeySet;
        Write-Verbose ('Key storage flags is: {0}' -f $KeyStorageFlags);
        $pfxcert.Import($Path, $Password, $KeyStorageFlags);

        # Create the X509 store and import the certificate
        $store = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store -ArgumentList My, LocalMachine -ErrorAction Stop;
        $store.Open([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]::ReadWrite);
        $store.Add($pfxcert);
        $store.Close();

        Write-Output -InputObject $pfxcert;
    }
    catch 
    {
        throw $_;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm looking at the same sort of thing. The problem I have is this sets the permissions on the file system, but not permissions on the private key itself (e.g. inside certificate manager right click the cert->all tasks-> manage private keys). Any idea how to modify that?

Answer (score 4):

The script provided worked for me (thanks!) with one change, due to a windows bug (see [Why does Set-Acl on the drive root try to set ownership of the "object"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622124/why-does-set-acl-on-the-drive-root-try-to-set-ownership-of-the-object))

#### Here is the updated script:

```
function Set-CertificatePermission
{
 param
 (
    [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]$pfxThumbPrint,

    [Parameter(Position=2, Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]$serviceAccount
 )

 $cert = Get-ChildItem -Path cert:\LocalMachine\My | Where-Object -FilterScript { $PSItem.ThumbPrint -eq $pfxThumbPrint; };

 # Specify the user, the permissions and the permission type
 $permission = "$($serviceAccount)","Read,FullControl","Allow"
 $accessRule = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule -ArgumentList $permission;

 # Location of the machine related keys
 $keyPath = $env:ProgramData + "\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\";
 $keyName = $cert.PrivateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.UniqueKeyContainerName;
 $keyFullPath = $keyPath + $keyName;

 try
 {
    # Get the current acl of the private key
    $acl = (Get-Item $keyFullPath).GetAccessControl()

    # Add the new ace to the acl of the private key
    $acl.AddAccessRule($accessRule);

    # Write back the new acl
    Set-Acl -Path $keyFullPath -AclObject $acl;
 }
 catch
 {
    throw $_;
 }
}
```

Comment: One addition only: GetAccessControl in try-catch is not a cmdlet, needs to be in parentheses. Otherwise, looks cool :)

Comment: For anyone who comes along and tries to use this answer, the line with $acl in the try-catch should look like this:
$acl = (Get-Item $keyFullPath).GetAccessControl('Access')

Comment: I notice this is granting "Read,FullControl". When does "FullControl" need to be included there, and when would just "Read" be enough?